# Dictionary extension in Swift is not recognized

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift4, swift-extensions

I am trying to extend Dictionary with the following code:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Value: AnyObject {

    var jsonString: String? {
    if let dict = (self as AnyObject) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: UInt.allZeros))
            if let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                return string
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    return nil
    }

}
```

Where I write something like:

```
let x: [String: String] = ["": ""]    
x.jsonString
```

I get this error:

```
Value of type '[String: String]' as no member 'jsonString'
```

Anything I am missing?

Comment: `String` is a value type and doesn't conform to `AnyObject`.  Try using `Any` instead.

Comment: **where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Value: Any {**

Comment: Sorry, nothing works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to constrain Dictionary Value type at all:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    var jsonString: String? {
        guard let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self)
        else { return nil }
        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. Maybe it is related with Swift 4?

Comment: Doesn’t work it is too vague. I have tested it here with a dictionary [String:String] and it work as expected

Comment: Same error...  not sure why I keep getting it... Maybe the file of the extension is somehow not recognized...?

Comment: Make sure your file is listed in the Compile Sources in your app targets build phases

Comment: The file is listed in Compile Sources, but it kept not working, so I copied the extension to another file with another working extension and it works. Strange thing... THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

Since `String` is a value type , look for it's

```
public struct String {
```

and `AnyObject` refers to any instance of a class only , and is equivalent to `id` in Objective-C , so this declaration of x

`[String: String]` doesn't fit with `[String: AnyObject]`

because `Any` refers to any instance of a class, **struct**, or enum so it'll fit perfectly